# .NET MAUI iOS MSAL authentication login screen not showing in Release mode (Testflight)

Tags: maui, azure-ad-msal, msal

I am adding MSAL authentication to a .NET MAUI application as described here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication](https://stackoverflow.com)
It works as expected in the iOS simulator as well when debugging on a device. Unfortunately, testing with an Ad-Hoc deployment through TestFlight is not working. The app will not show the MSAL login screen. The app seems to freeze.
We are using the following packages:

- Microsoft.Graph: 5.39.0
- Microsoft.Identity.Client: 4.59.0

The Entitlement for KeyChainAccess seems to be available in the Ad-Hoc-build. I checked it following this documentation: [https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1798/_index.html](https://stackoverflow.com).

Has someone experienced similar problems with release builds in Testflight.
Currently we are stuck with the rollout of our .NET MAUI app.